# Octave: ImportError when using symbolic package

Tags: python, octave, sympy, importerror, mpmath

I first built Octave from source using:

```
$brew install --build-from-source octave
```

Then I installed the symbolic package from within octave using:

```
$pkg install -forge symbolic
```

After that I did:

```
$pkg load symbolic
```

On using syms function it gave an ImportError that Sympy is not installed. So, I installed Sympy using:

```
$sudo pip install --user sympy
```

After that I tried using syms again and now it gives this error:

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<string>", line 1, in <module>
 File "/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/sympy/__init__.py", line 20, in <module>
 raise ImportError("SymPy now depends on mpmath as an external library. "
 ImportError: SymPy now depends on mpmath as an external library. See 
 http://docs.sympy.org/latest/install.html#mpmath for more information.
 OctSymPy v2.5.0: this is free software without warranty, see source.
 Initializing communication with SymPy using a popen2() pipe.
 error: Python cannot import SymPy: have you installed SymPy?
 error: called from
 assert_have_python_and_sympy at line 37 column 5
 python_ipc_popen2 at line 78 column 5
 python_ipc_driver at line 58 column 13
 python_cmd at line 164 column 9
 valid_sym_assumptions at line 38 column 10
 assumptions at line 82 column 7
 syms at line 97 column 13
```

Please tell me how to fix this.
OS: macOS Sierra 10.12.4
GNU Octave, version 4.2.1

Comment: Usually it's either `sudo` OR `--user` with pip. And make sure pip refers to pip2, the python2 version. Nevermind: install `mpmath` as well?

Comment: @AndrasDeak My pip version is 1.5.4 and python is 2.7. What do I do now?

Comment: Install mpmath.

Comment: mpmath is already installed. I had included the output of `$pip install --user mpmath` in the question but was deleted by someone who edited my question. It says mpmath is up to date.

Comment: Then pip might be pip3. Try installing explictly with pip2. Otherwise I'm out of ideas.

Comment: what happens when you open a python terminal and attempt to import sympy? (try both python2 and python3).

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou It showed error on importing sympy from within Python too. I fixed it by uninstalling both mpmath and sympy and reinstalling them with --user.

Comment: @TasosPapastylianou It showed error on importing sympy from within Python too. I fixed it by uninstalling both mpmath and sympy and reinstalling them with --user.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Fixed it by uninstalling mpmath and sympy first using:

```
$brew uninstall sympy
$brew uninstall mpmath
```

Then reinstalling them:

```
$pip install --user mpmath
$pip install --user sympy
```

Now everything works!